Decimal separator not changing when importing data from excel and when applying mean to groupby
I am importing some excel data with different column types. One of them is float and while the decimal separator in excel is a comma, a dot is imported.
What is more, when i do a groupby.mean on some columns, the result has a dot as a comma separator.
This does not change even though i set the locale to germany and even though i specifically add the decimal arg in pd.read_excel:
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8')
data = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name="data", header=1, decimal=',')

I am working on a mac with Sonoma.

The decimal=',' parameter is used to tell pandas what character to recognise as the decimal separator in text items that are imported. It does not control the display of the imported data.

You can control how floats are displayed, including using comma separator, after they have been imported see docs link

@user19077881 data.style.format(decimal=',') doesn't work. Column still shows a dot. I am befuddled.

EXcel's data is internationalised although may display in localised format depending on operating system level locale preferences, and number formatting preferences in excel. In this case setting decimal value on pd.read_excel will not do anything in particular. The thousands and decimal parameters help in converting localised formats into the international format that pandas needs for numeric data.

pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format creates and object that will use HTML and CSS to display in a Jupyter Notebook. It also works in an iPython interactive window in Visual Studio Code. It will not display in a terminal/console. using formatted styles, its best not to use locale formatted strings on macOS, since many locales on macOS do not have thousands separators defined.

There are a few things to unpick in this question:

what's happening when you import data into a dataframe
how to display a dataframe using localised formats

For pandas to process numbers and work with them, they need to be integers or floating point numbers. For Python, and by extension Pandas, this means that the numbers need to be in an international format, i.e. no grouping (thousands) separator and the period as a decimal separator.
Pandas provides a non-locale aware way to handle formatted numbers when reading from or writing to files. When reading into a dataframe it is possible to specify which grouping (thousands) and decimal separators that are used in localised formatted numbers when data is being read. The methods for importing data into a dataframe have both thousands and decimal parameters.
Numeric data in Excel will already be in internationalised form, but display may be localised format, even though data is international format. In Excel you can set language, but this controls text transformation and spellchecking. Number formats are controlled by the system locale, and this only affects the display of locale formatted numbers, not the actual number itself.
Reading directly from excel into a Pandas dataframe will automatically give you the internationalised integers or floats. If you import excel data to CSV or TSV, it may be internationalised or in localised format.
When reading from an Excel worksheet, you should only need to specify thousands and decimal if the data was entered into Excel as a string rather than as a number, which would be rare.
So for a TSV file, the command would look something like:
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.tsv', sep="\t", thousands=".", decimal=",")

In your example, you need and have the numbers in internationalised format.
If you data is using non-Arabic digits (sometimes referred to as native digits), or is using an alternative grouping scheme, it will be necessary to write a function to convert the localised strings. But this isn't needed for data conforming to a German locale.
Now the fun starts with displaying data using locale formatted strings.
Jupyter:
pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format provides a method for customising the display of a dataframe. It creates a pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object which uses HTML and CSS for formatting the dataframe. This styled dataframe will display in a Jupyter notebook, it will also display in an iPython interactive window in Visual Studio Code. Unfortunately, it will not display in a terminal.
You need your numbers in internationalised format in Pandas to be able to work with numeric data. But when displaying a dataframe its better to display localised strings.
First, we'll setup an example dataframe, with a column with integers and a column with floating point numbers. The distinction between datatypes will become significant later in the discussion.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import locale

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': np.random.randint(50000,300000,size=10),
    'B': (10 + np.random.rand(10,))*500
})
df
#   A   B
# 0 85683   5305.871931
# 1 68638   5382.953928
# 2 70463   5259.208994
# 3 174605  5148.400251
# 4 282422  5093.860614
# 5 171974  5040.370634
# 6 186592  5369.220148
# 7 109465  5220.654611
# 8 83800   5079.154934
# 9 214580  5439.968516

There are two approaches to handling formatting of numbers:

locale insensitive approach
locale sensitive approach

The locale insensitive approach works in most instances, and makes it easier for cross-platform code, i.e. it will work in the absence of an installed locale or where locale data differs across platforms. It will fail if you need to use native digits, or the target number format doesn't follow the common grouping scheme. But it will work fine for German.
df.style.format(thousands=".", decimal=",", precision=2)
#   A   B
# 0 85.683  5.305,87
# 1 68.638  5.382,95
# 2 70.463  5.259,21
# 3 174.605 5.148,40
# 4 282.422 5.093,86
# 5 171.974 5.040,37
# 6 186.592 5.369,22
# 7 109.465 5.220,65
# 8 83.800  5.079,15
# 9 214.580 5.439,97

The second approach is to use locale based formatting, but this is more complex on macOS. For example if we look at the de_DE.UTF-8 locale on macOS:
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8')
locale.localeconv()['thousands_sep']
# ''
number = 12345.6789
print(locale.format_string('%.2f', number, grouping=True))
# 12345,68

There are two things to note here: the de_DE.UTF-8 has an empty string for the thousands separator, and when you format a number, specifying the use of the grouping separator, there is no grouping separator.
This will affect the use of locale formatted strings in Pandas.
number_format = lambda x: locale.format_string('%d', x, grouping=True) if int(x) == x else locale.format_string('%.2f', x, grouping=True)
df.style.format(number_format)
#   A   B
# 0 85683   5305,87
# 1 68638   5382,95
# 2 70463   5259,21
# 3 174605  5148,40
# 4 282422  5093,86
# 5 171974  5040,37
# 6 186592  5369,22
# 7 109465  5220,65
# 8 83800   5079,15
# 9 214580  5439,97

As can be seen, no grouping separators are available. It is possible to use a private method to override the macOS locale data:
locale._override_localeconv = {'thousands_sep': '.'}
locale._override_localeconv["grouping"] = [3, 0]
df.style.format(number_format)
#   A   B
# 0 85.683  5.305,87
# 1 68.638  5.382,95
# 2 70.463  5.259,21
# 3 174.605 5.148,40
# 4 282.422 5.093,86
# 5 171.974 5.040,37
# 6 186.592 5.369,22
# 7 109.465 5.220,65
# 8 83.800  5.079,15
# 9 214.580 5.439,97

If we override the thousands separator value and the grouping type, the dataframe will be displayed as we require.
Console / terminal:
Unfortunately, pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format will not work in a terminal.
Pandas provides options that will globally specify the formatting of floating point numbers independent of the dataframe styling:
pd.options.display.float_format =  lambda x: locale.format_string('%.2f', x, grouping=True)
df
# A B
# 0 85683   5.305,87
# 1 68638   5.382,95
# 2 70463   5.259,21
# 3 174605  5.148,40
# 4 282422  5.093,86
# 5 171974  5.040,37
# 6 186592  5.369,22
# 7 109465  5.220,65
# 8 83800   5.079,15
# 9 214580  5.439,97

Unfortunately there is no method available for similar formatting capabilities of integers.
Edit:
One way of localising display of a dataframe in a terminal is by using an additional library such as rich or tabulate to display the dataframe in the terminal or console.
I'll modify rich_display_dataframe() as an example:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import locale
import contextlib
from rich.errors import NotRenderableError

def rich_display_dataframe(df, title="Dataframe", vfunc=None) -> None:
    """Display dataframe as table using rich library.

    Modified version of rich_display_dataframe() by @izikeros
    at https://gist.github.com/izikeros/b0d32072f234fba73650eb4b1e9c0017

    Args:
        df (pd.DataFrame): dataframe to display
        title (str, optional): title of the table. Defaults to "Dataframe".
        vfunc (Callable, optional): vectorised function
    Raises:
        NotRenderableError: if dataframe cannot be rendered
    Returns:
        rich.table.Table: rich table
    """
    from rich import print
    from rich.table import Table

    # ensure dataframe contains only string values
    df = df.astype(str)

    table = Table(title=title)
    for col in df.columns:
        table.add_column(col, justify="right")
    for row in df.values:
        with contextlib.suppress(NotRenderableError):
            if vfunc:
                row = vfunc(row)
            table.add_row(*row)
    print(table)

The function has been modified to adjust justification of values in table cells, and passing in a function to process the Numpy array containing data of a dataframe row.
We then create an example dataframe and override the macOS de_DE.UTF-8 locale data:
np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': np.random.randint(50000,300000,size=10),
    'B': (10 + np.random.rand(10,))*500
})

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8')
locale._override_localeconv = {'thousands_sep': '.'}
locale._override_localeconv["grouping"] = [3, 0]

Then provide a vectorised function:
number_format = lambda x: locale.format_string('%d', int(x), grouping=True) if "." not in x else locale.format_string('%.2f', float(x), grouping=True)
vf = np.vectorize(number_format)

Then pass the dataframe and function to the rich_display_dataframe() function:
rich_display_dataframe(df, vfunc=vf)
#       Dataframe
# ┏━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━┓
# ┃       A ┃        B ┃
# ┡━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━┩
# │  85.683 │ 5.305,87 │
# │  68.638 │ 5.382,95 │
# │  70.463 │ 5.259,21 │
# │ 174.605 │ 5.148,40 │
# │ 282.422 │ 5.093,86 │
# │ 171.974 │ 5.040,37 │
# │ 186.592 │ 5.369,22 │
# │ 109.465 │ 5.220,65 │
# │  83.800 │ 5.079,15 │
# │ 214.580 │ 5.439,97 │
# └─────────┴──────────┘

